# HLSL lighting based on texture pixels instead of screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, fragment-shader, shaderlab

In HLSL, how can I calculate lighting based on pixels of a texture, instead of pixels that make up the object?

In other words, if I have a 64x64px texture being rendered on a 1024x768px screen, I want to calculate the lighting as it affects the 64x64px space, resulting in jagged pixels instead of a smooth line.

I've researched dozens of answers but I'm not sure how I can determine at all times if a fragment is a part of a pixel that should be fully lit or not. Maybe this is the wrong approach?

The current implementation uses a diffuse texture and a normal map. It results in what appear as artifacts (diagonal lines) in the output:

[image]

[image]

Note: The reason it *almost* looks correct is because of the normal map, which causes some adjacent pixels to have normals that are angled just enough to light some pixels and not others.

Comment: you are already doing point sampling on both the diffuse texture and the normal textures right?

Comment: @BriceV. yes. I also [posted this on the gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/half-shaded-pixel-artifacts-on-2d-dynamic-lighting-shader) stack as well and shared the code there. It was written as a surface shader but I've since changed it to vert/frag shader.

Comment: I've decided to render to a texture and blow up the image into the camera in order to retain a pixel-perfect old-school look and it solves the problem, but it doesn't answer how this can be done in a shader u__u